# URL Rewrite not working as expected when product uploaded through magmi?

Tags: magento2, url-rewrite

I tried,

```
i) Stores-->Configuration-->Catalog-->Catalog-->SEO-->Use Categories Path for Product URLs to YES. 
ii) php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

I have again saved Categories but still no effect in url.
catalog/product/view/id/2140/room-set/category/11/

Comment: i think the reindexing is not working. Please make sure whether all indexing process completed or in processing stage.

Comment: @ShyamKrishnaSreekumar I have run the php bin/magento indexer:reindex successfully. But still no success

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 it does not exist *URL Rewrite index* so it does not make sense to reindex all.

You could use this extension: [“Regenerate Url rewrites” extension](https://github.com/olegkoval/magento2-regenerate_url_rewrites)